# how to generate random numbers using mid- square method?

Tags: r

I want to genearte random numbers using Von-Neuman middle square method in R.But
my code is returning the squared value.

```
midSquareRand <- function(seed, len) {
    randvector <- NULL
    for(i in 1:len) {
        value <- seed * seed   
        Y=as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(value),split="")))
        P=Y[3:6]
        seed=as.numeric(paste(P,collapse= ""))
        randvector <- c(randvector,seed)
  }
  return(randvector)
}


R = midSquareRand(6752, 50)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that Von-Neuman middle square method is not really a good PRNG.

One issue is that it is possible to have less than 2n digit in the sequence that is being generated, according to the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-square_method), the procedure is to pad leading zeros:

> To generate a sequence of n-digit pseudorandom numbers, an n-digit starting value is created and squared, producing a 2n-digit number. If the result has fewer than 2n digits, leading zeroes are added to compensate.

To achieve this, assuming n=4, we can add a line

```
Y = c(rep(0,8 - length(Y)), Y)
```

Also, it is possible that the middle portion ends up being zero and hence it will generate a deterministic sequence of zeros.

```
midSquareRand <- function(seed, len) {
    randvector <- NULL
    for(i in 1:len) {
        value <- seed * seed   
        Y=as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(value),split="")))
        Y = c(rep(0,8 - length(Y)), Y)
        P=Y[3:6]
        seed=as.numeric(paste(P,collapse= ""))
        randvector <- c(randvector,seed)
  }
  return(randvector)
}


R=midSquareRand(6752, 50)
```

gives me

```
[1] 5895 7510 4001   80   64   40   16    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[23]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[45]    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. To avoid generating zeros can we append 0 before the double digited generated number? will that help avoiding generating zeros?

Comment: I thought we are already appending 0 according to what the wikipedia suggested?